# Django apps with models.py in non-standard location

Tags: django

I've just started working on a codebase that the team I've joined is updating from using Django 1.4 to Django 1.8. Along with that change, it's being restructured into separate apps, and the layout is being changed in various ways.

`INSTALLED_APPS` has some apps, let's call them `foo` and `bar`, but their `models.py` files have been put into `db` subdirectories, that is `foo/db/models.py`.

Those models can be accessed from code (for example views) with `from foo.db.models import SomeModel`, and that seems to work.

However, from my reading of https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/applications/#initialization-process, particularly stage 2, models defined in `foo/db/models.py` rather than `foo/models.py` won't be found during application loading, which will cause a variety of issues.

Is it possible to support this non-standard location of `models.py` with a custom `AppConfig`, or in some other way?

To clarify, I think trying to have `models.py` in a non-standard location is a bad idea; I'm after confirmation to help make my argument to the rest of the team.

Answer (score 4):

The `models` submodule name is hardcoded, and it's the only module that is imported by Django during that step of the initialization process.

However, you can easily import your models inside your `models.py` file to ensure your models are imported at the correct time. If all your app's models are defined or imported in `foo.db.models`, you can simply use this:

```
# foo/models.py
from foo.db.models import *
```